# Console input within SBT does not echo to the screen

Tags: sbt

I hope I am missing something as it seems that keystrokes do not echo to the screen when a program is run within sbt.
Here is an example:

```
object ConsoleTest extends App {
  println("Enter a line:")
  val input = Console.readLine()
  println("You entered: " + input)
}
```

When I compile this simple code and run it from the command line (outside of sbt), I see the keystrokes as I type them for input and all works fine.
Unfortunately, when I use sbt to compile & run the same code, it does not echo the keystrokes to the screen at all. This is a disconcerting experience.
Has anyone else experienced this difference?
I've done some searching to see if others encounter this and whether there might be an sbt runtime parameter to allow keystroke echo. No luck so far.
I am using sbt-0.13.2 and the Java version of the above code experiences this same difference so it seems localized to running in the sbt environment.
Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: what OS are you running? What kind of terminal are you running sbt from?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro, MS-DOS shell, Java 1.7, Scala 2.10.4.
If it wasn't clear, the println works fine, it's the prior readLine that does not have its keystrokes echoed in SBT.

Comment: Do the input prints okay, even though chars are not echoed to the screen? Does it stop waiting for the input?

Comment: Yes, the println works fine. The only problem is that the keystrokes do not echo to the screen as they are typed; that's disconcerting. However, keystrokes are being processed as stdin and when return is typed, the program proceeds to the println. Colleagues of mine are also having the same difficulties, however it seems to work fine in *nix shells (but not Cygwin). Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I am having the same issue, OSX, bash, iTerm and Terminal.  sbt alone works, but sbt console doesn't.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No solution yet. Have canvassed many others and some experience it while some don't.

Comment: any solution yet? have the same problem on windows 8.1. I could swear that it has worked some weeks ago...

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 too

Answer (score 4):

This question is 2.5 years old, still no answer, so here goes :)

I tested with Windows 10, using Scala 2.12.1, SBT 0.13.13.1. The test program worked fine under Cmd and WSL's bash.

Historically this problem has been symptomatic of a JLine issue. You can override the JLine setting with the `jline.terminal` Java system variable to values like `auto`, `none` and `windows`. [Here are the complete docs](https://github.com/jline/jline2/wiki/Terminal-Factory-Configuration).

Here are some examples of how to specify various settings:

```
C:\work\experiments\sbt\optionTest>sbt run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\work\experiments\sbt\optionTest\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/work/experiments/sbt/optionTest/project/}optiontest-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to change-me (in build file:/C:/work/experiments/sbt/optionTest/)
[warn] there was one deprecation warning (since 2.11.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
Enter a line:
asdf
You entered: asdf
[success] Total time: 46 s, completed Jan 7, 2017 1:27:27 PM

C:\work\experiments\sbt\optionTest> sbt "-Djline.terminal=none" run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\work\experiments\sbt\optionTest\project
[info] Set current project to change-me (in build file:/C:/work/experiments/sbt/optionTest/)
Enter a line:
asdf
You entered: asdf
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Jan 7, 2017 1:28:12 PM

C:\work\experiments\sbt\optionTest> sbt "-Djline.terminal=windows" run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\work\experiments\sbt\optionTest\project
[info] Set current project to change-me (in build file:/C:/work/experiments/sbt/optionTest/)
Enter a line:
asdf
You entered: asdf
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Jan 7, 2017 1:28:26 PM
```

Comment: Works with `sbt "-Djline.terminal=none" console` also and is the only solution I've found for custom REPL stuff from sbt console.

Comment: @kberg: Frustrating since "none" is raw... meaning that one may not use built-in edits (like up-arrow support for recalling from history).  And "unix" setting requires a "double-tap" on the &lt;ENTER> key (or following &lt;ENTER> key with another "throwaway" key.  Choice:  Use "unix" to have editing support or use "none|off|false" to get rid of annoying "double-tap" feature.  :(

Comment: SBT forked JLine2, since then JLine has made a lot of progress and gone on to v3. However, SBT is still stuck with an orphaned version of v2. JLine3 does not have this problem.